# Copy of a PriorityQueue without Interfere with the original PriorityQueue

Tags: java, copy, priority-queue

I am trying to copy a PriorityQueue object.

My goal is to change some object of my Copy without modifying my original PriorityQueue

In order to do so I did a copy of my PriorityQueue and I delete a value of my copy, but when I check if my PriorityQueue is stil the same, unfortunately the original PriorityQueue was changed as well... If you have any suggestion it will be welcome.

Please find an example of what I tried :

```
public class PQExample
{
    public int id;
    public int price;
    public String name;
    public long date;

        public PQExample(int id, int price, String name, long time)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.price = price;
            this.name = name;
            this.date = time;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            PriorityQueueComparator pqc = new PriorityQueueComparator();
            PriorityQueue<PQExample> PQ = new PriorityQueue<PQExample>(pqc);
            int setID = 1000;
            int setDate = 0;
            PQ.add(new PQExample(setID++, 24 , "Mat", setDate++));
            PQ.add(new PQExample(setID++, 25 , "Tommy", setDate++));
            PQ.add(new PQExample(setID++, 22 , "Kate", setDate++));
            PQ.add(new PQExample(setID++, 26 , "Mary", setDate++));
            PQ.add(new PQExample(setID++, 24 , "Ronny", setDate++));
            PQExample valueToDel = new PQExample(1000,22,"Mat",0);

            PriorityQueue<PQExample> PQCopy = new PriorityQueue<PQExample>();
            PQCopy = PQ;

            //Now I want to delete only in PQCopy and not in PQ    
            PQCopy.remove(valueToDel);

            //Unfortunately Mat was deleted of both objects : PQ and PQCopy...
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                System.out.println("Queue in: " + i + " is " + PQ.peek().name + " with the price of " + PQ.peek().price);
                PQ.poll();
            }
        }
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o)
{
    if (o instanceof PQExample)
    {
        PQExample pqExample = (PQExample)o;
        return id == pqExample.id;
    }
    return false;
}


class PriorityQueueComparator implements Comparator<PQExample>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(PQExample o1, PQExample o2) {
        if (o1.price < o2.price){return 1;}else if (o1.price > o2.price){return -1;}
        else
        {if (o1.date<o2.date){return -1;}else{return 1;}}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing here:

```
PriorityQueue<PQExample> PQCopy = new PriorityQueue<PQExample>();
PQCopy = PQ;
```

Is:

1. Create a new object and store its reference in `PQCopy`.
2. Make `PQCopy` reference the same object as `PQ`

You need to create a new `PriorityQueue` object with the copy constructor instead:

```
PriorityQueue<PQExample> PQCopy = new PriorityQueue<>(PQ);
```

As you can read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue(java.util.Collection)):

> Creates a PriorityQueue containing the elements in the specified
> collection...

Be aware however that, although it copies the collection into a new one, the referenced objects are the same. This implies that if you change the contained objects' attributes, these changes will be noticed in the elements of both collections.

**EDIT**

```
    PriorityQueue<Integer> PQ= new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
    PQ.add(3);
    PQ.add(4);
    PriorityQueue<Integer> PQCopy = new PriorityQueue<>(PQ);
    PQCopy.remove();
    
    for(Integer i: PQ)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    
    for(Integer i: PQCopy)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

This other example shows how changes to the contained objects will affect the copied list too, if the contained objects are mutable:

```
   class CTest implements Comparable<CTest> {
        public CTest(int v) {
            this.v = v;
        }
        Integer v;

        @Override
        public int compareTo(CTest o) {
            return this.v.compareTo(o.v);
        }
    }

    PriorityQueue<CTest> PQ= new PriorityQueue<CTest>();
    PQ.add(new CTest(3));
    PQ.add(new CTest(4));
    PriorityQueue<CTest> PQCopy = new PriorityQueue<>(PQ);
    PQCopy.iterator().next().v = new Integer(6);
    
    for(CTest i: PQ)
    {
        System.out.println(i.v);
    }
    
    for(CTest i: PQCopy)
    {
        System.out.println(i.v);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, it was my first reflex to change the constructor, but eventhough it is still delete in both objects.

Comment: @Imagine You must be doing something else, the collection created with the copy constructor is a new object and and structural change on `PQ` won't affect `PQCopy` and vice-versa. Check my answer edit for an example.

Comment: @Imagine Note that the queues contain references, not the objects so any change to the elements attributes will be noted in both collections.

Comment: In your code you can act on the copy without affecting the original that is great !

Answer (score 6):

`PQcopy` is just a second reference to the actual `PriorityQueue` object.  You want to `clone` the original `PQ` instead of just assigning the reference.  [`PriorityQueue` has a constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue-java.util.PriorityQueue-) which does this for you:

```
PriorityQueue<PQExample> PQCopy = new PriorityQueue<PQExample>(PQ)
```

Incidentally, you should follow capitalization conventions for Java - starting variable names with capital letters is frowned upon.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, I did the change in the code, but it is still delete in both objects...

Comment: Did you delete the line `PQCopy = PQ;`? The constructor does all the copying, if you retain the explicit assignment afterwards you'll undo the constructor's good work and be right back where you started.

Comment: You were right; that was the line that I let and which made the wrong constructor